# Setting up a firewall on Ubuntu 14.04 with ufw having a dynamic IP address

Tags: ufw

is it possible to lock down my server using ufw to grant access only from my office? The problem is, my office IP is dynamic (not only in the first 16 bytes but the whole IP).

I had set the following rule to accept ssh connections:

```
-A ufw-user-input -s 217.84.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

The problem is, my IP address is now something like:

```
-A ufw-user-input -s 84.142.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

So as you can see, the whole thing changed, it was before in the range

```
217.84.0.0 - 217.84.255.255
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

My hostname is dynamic as well, so this makes it much more complicated.

Comment: this would work in case my hostname is static as well but it changes every day

Comment: What do you mean with `not only in the last 16 bytes but the whole IP`? The last 16 bytes is the entire IP address.

Comment: Either way. I suggest you switch to authentication methods that don't rely on IP addresses.

Comment: the first 16 sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by setting a hostname at the office, which would not change and be easily detected by the server? Than the server could adjust the firewall to the new ip of the hostname in question.

Comment: Do you know how is it possible to do that? I can't find much information on the subject.

Comment: You could connect through a VPN using a static IP. Your final IP would not change, wherever you connect from.

Comment: Yes, after some research I realized the best thing to do is set up a vpn, it will be useful as well to work from outside of the office, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Firewalls to work properly, it needs to know who to allow or block. In your case, it would not be much help on a security perspective if you allow the IP range of your dynamic IP. That still opens you up to a huge IP pool of possible intruders.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I don't think ufw can work with domains. If it could, then you could set a dynamic dns updater at your office.

The best way right now is to setup a VPN connection if you don't mind the latency.